# Populate DropDown from database in an edit view using MVC4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to MVC and trying to populate a dropdown list in the "create" view which is generated from a view model, but it returns with an error saying object reference is not an instance of an object. below is my code :

Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new AddRecipeViewModel());
}
```

Model Code:

```
public class DifficultyLevel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Difficulty { get; set; }
    }

public class AddRecipeViewModel

    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<RecipeReview> Reviews { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<DifficultyLevel> Difficulty { get; set; }

    }
```

View:

```
<div>
    <select>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Difficulty)
        {
            <option>@item.Difficulty</option>
        }
    </select>

</div>
```

Is there an easy workaround this ? as I will be adding more drop downs in this as I go along.

Thanks,
Vishal

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that is populating the object...your instantiating an object but there is nothing in it...you need to make a call to the database and get the values.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you need to use `virtual` in your view models.. that's usually only for the entity models.  but anyway, try adding a constructor to AddRecipeViewModel and set the collections equal to empty lists so they won't be null.

```
public class AddRecipeViewModel
{
    public AddRecipeViewModel()
    {
         Reviews = new List<RecipeReview>();
         Difficulty = new List<DifficultyLevel>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RecipeReview> Reviews { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<DifficultyLevel> Difficulty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So this worked partially and added the dropdown but did not populate it.I have 3 values stored (easy,medium and hard) in the database which I need to pull in here. will I have to write some LINQ?

Comment: I dont see how you are populating the list "Difficulty" it looks like an empty list @vishalvazkar

Comment: I have manually added these values to the database as they are fixed values.

Comment: obviously you will need to retrieve the values from the database if that is where they are stored.. or create an enum.. that's a case by case design decision..  you should watch the Pluralsight MVC tutorial to see how to use entity framework and mvc.  http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m6-ajax&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building

Comment: I am following these tutorials to make an application but was just stuck at this one step so thought would get some help from here.